# Can't create free-tier AWS RDS DB

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database, cloud, amazon-rds

I can't seem to create a 12-month free-tier AWS RDS DB running MySQL.

According to AWS, [the following requirements](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=tier%2312monthsfree&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=categories%23databases&trk=ps_a134p000006payEAAQ&trkCampaign=acq_paid_search_brand&sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_ND&sc_publisher=Google&sc_category=Database&sc_country=ND&sc_geo=EMEA&sc_outcome=acq&sc_detail=aws%20free%20rds&sc_content=Relational%20Database_e&sc_matchtype=e&sc_segment=531718064067&sc_medium=ACQ-P%7CPS-GO%7CBrand%7CDesktop%7CSU%7CDatabase%7CSolution%7CND%7CEN%7CText%7Cxx%7CEU&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!531718064067!e!!g!!aws%20free%20rds&ef_id=Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAkVeRPR4-WaHgXE3Z_kP63FnjDoCwrMfbI0Hqx7Ff4whERYl_d_NcaAvxGEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!531718064067!e!!g!!aws%20free%20rds) need to be met for a 12-month free-tier RDS DB:

> - 750 Hours per month of `db.t2.micro` database usage (applicable DB engines)
> - 20 GB of General Purpose (SSD) database storage
> - 20 GB of storage for database backups and DB Snapshots
> - Applicable engines: Managed Relational Database Service for MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, Oracle BYOL, or SQL Server.

When selecting the DB instance class in RDS via the AWS console, I can't find `db.t2.micro` as an option (the closest being `db.t3.micro`):
[AWS RDS DB instance class selection screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX6O3.png)

Following some tutorials available online, I have found out that back in the day, AWS allowed for a "free-tier" template, which is no longer available in my view: [AWS RDS DB templates screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFcjV.png).

How can I create a 12-month free-tier AWS DB running MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible reasons come to mind:

- The region / AZ you're trying doesn't have any t2.micro RDS instances available. Try a different AZ or different region. us-east-1 is usually a good bet
- It could be that the free tier offering hasn't kept up with the RDS instance availability. Nothing you can do about this.

Comment: Indeed, changing the region was the solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer it really helped

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Tim's Answer.

It could also be the DB Engine Version.

For example, for SQL Server.

- SQL Server 2019 and up, the DB instance class **db.t2.micro** is
  unavailable.
- SQL Server 2017 and below, the DB instance class **db.t2.micro** is
  available.

Try switching to SQL Server 2017.